# jquery hover remains hovered when cursor is moved away via mouse-wheel scrolling

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the jquery function or a bug on my code, but i can see the same behavior happening on the example at http://api.jquery.com/hover/

My implementation is that i have a pop up box that shows when the mouse is hovered over a product item, and the hidden when the mouse hovers out.

The issue is when the mouse is hovered and the pop up box shows, if I scroll down/up the page with the mousewheel/trackpad, while the mouse cursor is not on the product item anymore due to the scrolling, the hover-out behavior is not detected, and the pop up box remains in sight, remaining in the middle of the screen since its position is determined during the hover event, relative to the product's position on the screen.

Does this make sense ? Can anyone help ?

Comment: I believe is more of a JavaScript limitation, I'm sure I've seen it asked before somewhere in StackOverflow.

Comment: Is it possibly a browser issue? I tried this now in FF 7, and it I am not able to replicate the problem. What browser are  you using?

Comment: @mydoghasworms: I can replicate the error in Chrome 14

Comment: @mydoghasworms: WebKit (Safari, Chrome) does this, just hover over the "jquery" tag above until the info popup comes up then wheel away and the popup won't go away.

Comment: Oh yes, there it is: Just tried it in Chrome 14 as well, and now I can see it happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a somewhat intrusive solution, but it should work:

```
// The normal hover handler
$("#productElement").hover(function(){
  $("#otherElement").show();
},function(){
  $("#otherElement").hide();
});

// A global scroll handler that hides an specific
// element whenever the user scrolls.
$(document).scroll(function(){
  $("#otherElement").hide();
});
```

In the above code, `#productElement` would be the label that the user hovers to, and `#otherElement` would be the dialog that pops up on hover. That is just the basics of how it would work; you would adapt it to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, at least now I know it's a js limitation  with webkit browsers.

Comment: @Winterain: your welcome! Some browser-related bugs can really be a pain!